# WIFI not working on lenovo yoga 2 13 with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, secure-boot

i recently installed ubuntu 18.04 on a lenovo yoga 2 (not pro) and i cant seem to get the wifi on .
in wifi settings it says

```
       **No wifi adapter found
        make sure you have wifi adapter pluged in.**
```

the wifi was working fine on windows 10 and i have checked bios its enabled their as well. thank you all in advance for your help.
i have attatched the information from my wireless-info.txt file.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 Mar 2019 01:40 PKT +0500

Booted last: 03 Mar 2019 00:00 PKT +0500

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 14:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0623]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 048d:8350 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0489:e07a Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b40f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f3:0303 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0489:c022 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              667648  0
ideapad_laptop         32768  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    24576  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  45056  2 ideapad_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s20u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s20u1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.27/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s20u1
       valid_lft 2179sec preferred_lft 2179sec
    inet6 fe80::fe14:b94d:8d1c:5821/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s20u1  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s20u1 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20u1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.27 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       690     1  0 01:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20u1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         HMD Global
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Nokia 6.1 Plus
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20u1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/net/enp0s20u1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20u1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       2b31f589-069d-3749-8baa-d6d34db117f7
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.27/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.42.129, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.42.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1551561396
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.42.27
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::fe14:b94d:8d1c:5821/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   2b31f589-069d-3749-8baa-d6d34db117f7 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Karachi (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s20u1  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s20u1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     BFB309EF7C6C321F605D36E
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.18.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    4.994588] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0489-e07a.hcd failed with error -2
[    4.994592] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0489-e07a.hcd not found
[    5.053852] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: renamed from usb0
[    5.718092] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u1: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

```
##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0623]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

This shows that the correct `bcmwl-kernel-source` as the `wl` kernel module is installed, but not loaded.

```
##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled
```

It is not loaded because of Secure Boot. You can check it by running

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

You an see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules/762255#762255) for more details.