# How to download proper Wifi Drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

I previously used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS. And then I switched to the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. In previous Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi was working without any error. But same laptop in Ubuntu 18.04 it does not working. When I go to WiFi settings there is a message `No WiFi Adapter Found`.

First I thought it was a problem of hardware, But boot with windows (My laptop is dual boot) It is working properly.

This is the wireless info I got by following the steps given in the link here http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/44179.

pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/GgLDKf9P

WiFi Model: BCM43142

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS that's all you need to do.

Comment: This is a dupe of this one https://askubuntu.com/a/1122567/167850